# issue in iterating map type in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2, struts

I've tried to iterate the variable of map type in jsp .. but the result page shows nothing

product details is of type `Map<String,String>`

//Action

```
public String execute() {
productDetails = displayServiceDao.fetchProductDetailsService( product );}
public Map<String , String> getProductDetails() {
return productDetails;   
}
public void setProductDetails( Map<String , String> productDetails ) {
this.productDetails = productDetails;
}
```

//jsp

```
<s:iterator var="studentEntry" value="productDetails.entrySet()">
<s:property value="%{#studentEntry.getKey()}"/>
<s:property value="%{#studentEntry.getValue()}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Note:i am not adding values to map in action class..i add it through the return value of a   function

Comment: Create getter and setter for your map.

Comment: You'll need to decide whether you want to iterate over the key set, value set or entry set.

Comment: how to do that? @beny23

Comment: Show your action class and jsp.

Comment: @pravin: a map has a keySet and values collections, you can iterate over them but a map itself is not a collection.

Comment: @beny23: S2 can handle this.

Comment: @Pravin: Not enough info to help. How do you call your action? Is your map getting populated at all?

Comment: @AleksandrM i call action through another jsp .. My intention is to get values from database and display it through jsp .. i did the same in java using map ..it worked fine ..now i am trying the same through struts2 ,i am not getting it

Comment: @beny23 thanks a lot .. now i can understand map better .. but still struggling to convert

Comment: You can't call your action through "another jsp". Call it from your jsp. Don't mess up things for free.

Comment: does it really affect my issue??

Comment: Yes, if your map is empty because the values went lost between the two jsp...

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to decide what you want to do with the keys and values in your map. You could do:

```
<s:iterator value = "productDetails" >
    <s:property value="key"/>
    <s:property value="value"/>
</s:iterator>
```

N.b. this will iterate over the entrySet of you map and use a Map.Entry object which contains key and value properties.